# Programatically add user activity to timeline in Windows 10 Redstone build

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

Windows 10 Insider Preview build 17063 contains a [new Timeline feature](https://hothardware.com/news/windows-10-redstone-4-test-build-17063-rolls-out-timeline-feature).

How can I add user activity to this timeline in C#?

What SDK do I need?

Comment: see info here: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/12/19/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-17061-now-available/#Ybwu9pPvvAijDKqI.97

Answer (score 0):

Here's the blogpost talking about it (not the same as the one in comments):
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/12/19/application-engagement-windows-timeline-user-activities/